# Image in CSS nav bar

Tags: css, image, space, nav

I'm trying to add an icon as the last link in my navigation bar.

It is adding too much space to the entire ul, even though the image does not extend a single pixel beyond the blue gear.

I've tried setting margins, padding, and line-height to 0, it still extends the block.

Nav Bar
[nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QsDM.jpg)

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 14px 16px;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">PRODUCTION</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OFFICE</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">SALES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">MISC</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ADMIN</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">GEAR</a></li>
  <!--<li><a id="gear" href="#"><img src="gear.png"/></a></li> -->
</ul>
```

Image
[Gear Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mQeR.png)

Comment: Please post the image on an image host. I'd like to use it in a working example for you.

Comment: Did you clear the padding that you set in `li a { ... padding: 14px 16px; }` ? Something like `li a#gear { padding: 0; }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add in this CSS rule, to make sure the image never goes larger than the text around it.

```
.menu img {
  height:1em;
}
```

Without an accurate image file, I can't come up with a more specific/elegant solution:

Here's a working example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LZRaWL

If the gear is too small, then reduce the padding and increase the size of the gear. Here's a secondary example in which I've taken advantage of the relative sizing for `em` units:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMwEmj

Comment: Thank you, I added the image to my post